# How to distribute .Net Core 3.1 with a WPF application

Tags: wpf, .net-core, installation

I am currently shipping a WPF application that targets .NET Framework 4.7.1. Almost all Windows systems nowadays have .NET Framework 4.7.1 (or greater) already installed.  For the few users that don't, my app's installer provides a link to the Microsoft's download page. All security updates are handled by Windows update.

**Now, I'd like to start targeting .NET Core 3.1.** Many users do not have it on their machines. How can I get my app to run on wide range of machines, without burdening the users? One solution I thought of is to have my installer download .NET Core installer from Microsoft and run it. Am I going to mess anything up on the user's system if I do this? Is it going to be updated automatically by Microsoft updates?

Comment: First match in a Google search of your question's title: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/3-ways-to-deploy-a-winforms-or-wpf-net-core-application

Comment: You might want to use .net 4.8 (instead of 4.7.1) and .net 5.0 (instead of 3.1) for multiplatform.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Very helpful link. I googled a few things and when I couldn't find a solution, I came to SE and thought carefully how to phrase the question. Should have Googled again after phrasing it this way. Feel free to post an answer and suggest self-contained deployment with assembly linking to trim the app size.